# Don't understand cause of TypeError in my distance calculator

Tags: python

I am new to python and I was trying to write a program to calculate the distance formula between two points. I keep getting a type error on line 11 when I try subtracting the expressions. What am I doing wrong?

```
import math
print("Distance Formula and Slope Calculator")

#store coordinates
x1 = input('x1')
y1 = input('y1')
x2 = input('x2')
y2 = input('y2')

#(x2-x1) and (y2-y1)
expression_1 = x2 - x1
expression_2 = y2 - y1

#square expressions
squared_1 = expression_1**2
squared_2 = expression_2**2

#add expressions
added = squared_1 + squared_2

#square root
distance = math.sqrt(added)

#show distance
print(f"The distance between ({x1}, {y1}) and ({x2}, {y2}) is {distance}")
```

Comment: Read the error and apply your intuition to it. It pretty much spells everything out for you.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You need to cast it to an integer before you can do substraction as `int(input("x1"))` because `input` returns a string.

Comment: I believe the behavior of `input` changed between Python 2 and Python 3.

Comment: @MarkRansom Yeah in python 2 it's `raw_input`